# Colon or Semicolon for this sentence

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, colons

> If I ever told you I like apples: I lied.

or

> If I ever told you I like apples; I lied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This needs to be a **comma** because the first part of the sentence ("If I ever told you I like apples") cannot stand on its own as a sentence; "I lied" is needed for it to make sense. This is called a *'dependent clause'*.

If the two clauses were *independent* (they could stand on their own as sentences), then a semicolon would be needed. To use a comma between two independent clauses is known as 'comma splicing' and is considered grammatically incorrect.

Hope the background info helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you want is a comma:

> If I ever told you I like apples, I lied.